# NodeJS - Testing model, not receiving callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an issue with some mocha tests in node - I'm testing a model and calling the model's method to get a response - simply the Model.findOne method.

In the main code base it returns as expected, (as it does when querying in the database) but when testing it fails to reach the callback and the tests just time out.. any ideas what the issue might be please?

Output from Mocha:

```
  1) user model tests check user exists email should equal input: test123@gmail.com:
 Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

To me, it seems like a configuration issue - But I cannot work out where.

Code below:

userTest.js

```js
var Chance = require('chance');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var supertest = require('supertest');
var api = supertest('http://localhost:3000');
var chance = new Chance();
var User = require('../api/models/UserModel').User;

var validUser = {
    email: 'test123@gmail.com',
    password: "123456"
};

describe.only('user model tests', function () {

    describe('check user exists', function () {

        it("email should equal input: " + validUser.email, function (done) {
            User.findOneByEmail(validUser.email, function (err, result) {
                expect(result.email).to.equal(validUser.email);
                done();
            });
        });

    });
});
```

UserModel.js

```js
UserSchema.statics.findOneByEmail = function(email, callback) {
    this.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
            return callback(systemError());
        }

        if (!user) {
            return callback(fileNotFoundError());
        }

        return callback(null, user);
    });
};
```

Comment: can you show the listing of `User.findOneByEmail` function?
I think it can be the origin of trouble. Maybe it throws error, and executing script is stopped on this function.

Comment: I've added it in. I use the same function in other parts of the code and it works as expected, I'm just not getting any response in the test environment.

Comment: You should use "user.findOneByEmail", because you've already injected the class "User" in "user".

Comment: Ah that was a typo my side whilst getting it ready for SO. Updating the question now, thanks. (But didn't make any difference).

Comment: Try to console log the User object in callback, maybe it doesn't have the property  "findOneByEmail".

Comment: It logs fine, and otherwise it would throw an undefined error.

Comment: The problem may not be in the code you show, by the way, what is "this" in your "findOneBeEmail" function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94574/discussion-between-sayume-and-phil-hudson).

Comment: I have feeling that `systemError()` and `fileNotFoundError()` can be undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you are using mongoose. So, before starting tests you must connect to your mongodb first. For example you can do it in `before` section.

Mongoose [connect](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect) function supports a callback.

```
before(function (done) {
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', done);
});
```